# How to split data into columns in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split

I have data in table:

| id | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 Covid-19 [cases] |
| 2 | 1.1 Covid-19 [deaths] |

I want to split the data into columns. To get below output:

| id | questionid | question_name | sub_question_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | Covid-19 | cases |
| 2 | 1.1 | Covid-19 | deaths |

Is any function to get above output.?

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far with the documented string functions? Add your current query to your question and explain where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use regexp_replace, in this example, the regexp_replace will replace the square brackets (first and third groups) group 1 -> `^(\[)`, group 3 -> `(\])$` by the second group `(.*)`.
the third argument `\2` in the end of the function indicates what group should remain in the text.

```
select 
    id,  
    split_part(question, ' ', 1) p1,
    split_part(question, ' ', 2) p2,
    regexp_replace(split_part(question, ' ', 3), '^(\[)(.*)(\])$', '\2') p3
from 
    covid;
```

Here is the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMFwoy4j7GVcPPFbNq2wPj/0)

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is using the much useful PostgreSQL `SPLIT_PART` function, which allows you to split on a character (in your specific case, the space). As long as you don't need brackets for the last field, you may split on the open bracket and remove the last bracket with the `RTRIM` function.

```
SELECT id, 
       SPLIT_PART(question, ' ', 1)             AS questionid,
       SPLIT_PART(question, ' ', 2)             AS question_name,
       RTRIM(SPLIT_PART(question, '[', 2), ']') AS sub_question_name
FROM  tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYr2TvzGxGNss22FSnfpdf/0).

You can deepen your understanding of these functions on PostgreSQL [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) related to the string functions.

---

**EDIT**: For a more advanced matching, you should consider using regex and PostgreSQL [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

```
SELECT id, 
       (REGEXP_MATCHES(question, '^[\d\.]+'))[1]         AS questionid,
       (REGEXP_MATCHES(question, '(?<= )[^[]+'))[1]      AS question_name,
       (REGEXP_MATCHES(question, '(?<=\[).*(?=\]$)'))[1] AS sub_question_name
FROM  tab
```

Regex for `questionid` Explanation:

- `^`: start of string
- `[\d\.]+`: any existing combination of digit and dots

Regex for `question_name` Explanation:

- `(?<= )`: positive lookbehind that matches a space before the match
- `[^[]+`: any existing combination of any character other than `[`

Regex for `sub_question_name` Explanation:

- `(?<=\[)`: positive lookbehind that matches an open bracket before the match
- `.*`: any character
- `(?=\]$)`: positive lookahead that matches a closed bracket after the match

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYr2TvzGxGNss22FSnfpdf/1).

Comment: It working. but what if question_name length two or more. 
e.g. 1.2 Total population by 2022[male]

Comment: Check the updates on this answer. @Sudarshan